# Изменение ответа от сервера в формате JSON

Tags: javascript, json, api

Всем доброго времени суток, столкнулся с задачей, на которую не могу найти решение. Суть заключается в том, чтобы изменить полученный ответ от сервера в виде такой строки
`{"v":100000000,"e":false,"ec":0,"cc":"RU"}`
А поменять нужно, к примеру вот так `{"v":1000,"e":false,"ec":0,"cc":"RU"}`, то есть изменить значение "v" и желательно не на один раз, а придумать что-то в виде автоматического обработчика. Буду признателен, если кто-то поможет и расскажет, как это реализовать, какие утилиты нужно использовать) (У меня пока что единственный вариант - это прокси)

Comment: Если покажите, как вы принимаете ответ и обрабатываете, возможности будет больше

Comment: В том и проблема, что ответ этот вытянут из POST запроса и просмотрен в консоли браузера (вкладка 'Network') А как его обработать и через какой способ изменить, сам не знаю

Comment: т.е. вы собираетесть делать не в коде сайта?

Comment: Вот я и хотел узнать, если это прокси какой-нибудь, обработчик вставляется в код, или же программа, которая отдельно идет

Comment: Если протокол http, то можно что то типа Charle использовать. Если https, то ближе к невозможному(нужны сертификаты для расшифровки трафика)

Comment: Если к примеру charle proxy , его можно не просто для теста использовать, а для постоянной обработки?

Answer (score 0):

> изменить полученный ответ от сервера в виде такой строки `{"v":100000000,"e":false,"ec":0,"cc":"RU"}` А поменять нужно, к примеру вот так `{"v":1000,"e":false,"ec":0,"cc":"RU"}`

Как вариант...

```js
let str = '{"v":100000000,"e":false,"ec":0,"cc":"RU"}'
str = JSON.parse(str)
str.v = 1000
str = JSON.stringify(str)
console.log(str)
```

Comment: А не могли бы вы подсказать, где этот метод лучше реализовать?

Comment: Так получил данные и преобразовывай...

Comment: Так в том и прикол, что эту строку я вытянул из консоли (ответа на запрос), в ответе одна строка, а мне надо, чтобы была другая. Вот я хочу понять, чем воспользоваться, чтобы ответ изменяло, прокси каким-нибудь, или ещё чего)

Comment: Этот ответ ведь кто-то получает... Там и меняй...